# Create product in Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Financials

Tags: postman, odata, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I try to create a product (item) using OData V4 URL available in Web Services section in Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Financials as shown below.

[image]

I use Postman to execute the POST request. Each request is proceed with an authenticated and valid account.

The POST OData V4 URL is taken from the Web Services sections example: `https://xyz.financials.dynamics.com:7048/MS/ODataV4/Company('my-company')/Items`

I also tried the entity "Item_Card", same result.

Here is the config set in Postman:

**Headers**
[image]

**Body**
[image]

When I execute the request, I get the following error:
[image]

What is the missing "Data object"? Is this a standard of OData V4 protocol? Do I must supply a "Data object" into the body?

Is there anyone encountered that error and could explain what is missing/not working?

### Update 2017-05-10

It seems that the REST endpoint is not available for Microsoft Dynamics Financials build < 16552. I currenly use build 16259.

### Update 2017-05-23

I am now running on build 16552. I still get the same error. The update seems to have no effect on the POST request.

Comment: I am getting same problem. Have you solved it ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I will update this post if I succeed.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today.
I am using SoapUI for testing a simple webservice on a custom table in an on premise version nav2017.

In the end I found out that I was writing a Date on a Date field in NAV. After changing that to DateTime and sending a correct date time string it was working.

It probably does not answer your question as I see no date in your body, but maybe for others who are searching for the error "Data Object not provide" it might help to check if the datatypes used in the body matches the datatypes in NAV.

Regards, Henry Verheij

Comment: I have just checked and you can also write the data in this format "2017-06-30T00:00:00Z" on a Date field in NAV.

Answer (score 1):

I receive this error as well. In my case I was adding a vendor and I missed the NO. (this field is not on the interface'vendor card', but it appears in the listing and is mandatory in the service, however no documentation about it). So my guess you probable is missing a mandatory field.

PS:I used [OData v4 Client Code Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator) to generate my proxy from the metadata.

Comment: Seems legit, I will give a shot.